# Implicit Intent is not working due to context issue

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, android-recyclerview

Here is my code :-

**Favourite Activity**

```
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.startActivity
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import java.security.AccessController.getContext


//this is my calling activity
class FavouriteActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.favourite_activity)
        val mToolbar: Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_favourite)
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar)
        getSupportActionBar()?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar()?.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        setTitle("Favourite Activity");


        //getting recyclerview from xml
        val recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView) as RecyclerView
        //adding a layoutmanager
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false)
        //it can be staggered and grid
        //creating our adapter
        val adapter = CustomAdapter(star)   //here I am calling the adapter activity
        //now adding the adapter to recyclerview
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter

    }
  override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        onBackPressed()
        return true
    }
}
```

**CustomAdapter class**

```
class CustomAdapter(val userList: ArrayList<User>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    //this method is returning the view for each item in the list
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CustomAdapter.ViewHolder {
        val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.list_layout_favourite, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(v)
    }


    //this method is binding the data on the list
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CustomAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bindItems(userList[position])

        holder.imgCopy.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            holder.shareString(userList[position])
            Toast.makeText(holder.itemView.getContext(),"Copy Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        })
    }

    //this method is giving the size of the list
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return userList.size
    }

    //the class is holding the list view
    class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        val imgCopy: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_copy) as ImageView

        val textViewName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle) as TextView

        fun bindItems(user: User) {

            textViewName.text = user.name

        }

        fun shareString(user: User)
        {
            val message : String = user.name
            val intent = Intent()
            intent.action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,message)
            intent.type = "text/plain"
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Share to :"))    ///Issue occur right here
          }}}
```

**Getting error :** Required context , found Intent.

it is working fine in other FragmentActivity.
I have tried various methods to called the context. but anything is not working.
I have also passed the context from Fragment activity, but that also not worked.
Please let me know is there any way to start Intent. 
As I am always getting error and stuck due to this.

Comment: on which line are you getting error?

Comment: startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Share to :"))    ///Issue occur right here

Answer (score 1):

The `startActivity` available in the ViewHolder class is different from the  one available in activites. So in this method (available in viewholder), the first parameter should be a context. So pass the context as follows:

```
startActivity(itemView.context, Intent.createChooser(intent,"Share to :"))
```

Comment: yes bro, working    startActivity(itemView.context, Intent.createChooser(intent,"Share to :"),null)